# How to make a specific region from picture box as grid of a specific number of cells in C#

Tags: c#, grid

The following is the code to make a grid of 100 cells for a region of 500*500 of a picture box. This region start from x = 300 y = 200 and end in x = 800 y = 700. Each cell side equal to 50 pixel.

```
//makes grid in picture box
        private void drawGrid()
        {
            int numOfCells = 100;
            int cellSize = 50;
            Pen p = new Pen(Color.Blue);


            for (int i = 0; i < numOfCells; i++)
            {
                // Vertical
                paper.DrawLine(p, i * cellSize, 200, i * cellSize, 700);
                // Horizontal
                paper.DrawLine(p, 300, i * cellSize, 800, i * cellSize);
            }
        }
```

I got additional lines outside the grid and I don't know how to remove them, kindly refer to the following snapshot in the following link to understand me more.

[snapshot(here)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/28wovig5xdz4iky/dgdgdg.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping and drawing two lines for each cell. However, since you are drawing a square grid, you want to loop `Math.Sqrt(numOfCells) + 1` times to draw 11 lines in this case to include the border.

You also want to offset the `i*cellSize` expressions by your x and y values.
So, `paper.DrawLine(p, i * cellSize, 200, i * cellSize, 700);` becomes `paper.DrawLine(p, i * cellSize + 300, 200, i * cellSize + 300, 700);` and a similar offset by `200` on the horizontal line.

Comment: What changed? Can you take another screenshot?

Comment: Yes, it is working thank you. But when I minimize the form, this grid disappears !! any idea ??

Comment: Make sure you are drawing in the `onPaint()` event. Your picturebox needs to be redrawn to everytime it is painted. See [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a2a8ca0b-0772-4703-ac45-c09c4a7ccf17/graphics-disappear-after-minimizing-window?forum=vbgeneral)

Comment: Is there another way, because I call this method in another method after onPaint is called

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware, although I am very limited in my experience with PictureBox. You can, of course, store all of your information in a custom class and later draw it when `onPaint` is called.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this. It will work for you. You can set left and top.

```
private void drawGrid()
{
    int numOfCells = 100;
    int cellSize = 50;
    Pen p = new Pen(Color.Blue);

    int left = 50;// Left
    int top = 10;//  Top
    int width = cellSize * numOfCells;
    int height = cellSize * numOfCells;

        for (int i = 0; i <= numOfCells; i++)
        {
            // Vertical
            paper.DrawLine(p, i * cellSize + left, top, i * cellSize + left, height + top);
            // Horizontal
            paper.DrawLine(p, left, i * cellSize + top, width + left, i * cellSize + top);

        }
}
```